# Which configuration allows both sides to communicate? (see diagrams)

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, vpn

Please see the below two images.  I want to enable BOTH sides to initiate connections to each other and communicate successfully.  Both remote ends are connected via a separate VPN tunnel to the central site.

Which one is correct?  We're working with Cisco ASA's.

The first one

[image: First Image]

Or .. the second one

[image: Second Image]

Comment: These diagrams are not readable

Comment: Thanks for giving me some feedback, the images I added as links since no matter how I embedded the image there was no ability to zoom in!!  The linked images should be very clear!

Comment: No, your images are not very clear and fredpbaker is correct. They show up as a single tiny dot on a black background. Page is labeled blockpage.cgi(GIF Image, 2x1 pixels) Maybe you need to enable public viewership of the file in question?

Comment: I've flagged to have this deleted since I can't affect permissions or display capabilities of the photos and an answer isn't useful without this context.  There's been no response.

Comment: The images were always readable, you may just have had to zoom your browser view in to see the details.  Unless you have customized your mouse controls, in most browsers this can easily be done by holding down "Ctrl" and using the scroll wheel on the mouse.  The most recent edit will also allow you to click on the image to zoom.

Comment: lol - for me they were always readable too, but everyone else was like 'I can't see it' so then I switched to just creating links and they still complained the links went to small images.. whatever, glad to know I wasn't crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer (verified by Cisco VPN specialist) is Number 2.  The crypto ACL's and NAT are bi-directional by default assuming your outside interfaces are static.